# Modificar o añadir array en java con bucle for

Tags: java, array, update

Estoy realizando un ejercicio que debo realizar en un **array**, obligatoriamente. Se trata de un método para añadir nuevos laboratorios, o modificar su nombre si ya existe su identificador en el sistema. No consigo hacer que el método funcione. Es el siguiente:

```
public class Trial4C19Impl implements Trial4C19 {
private Laboratory[] laboratories;
private int numLaboratories;
boolean encontrado=false;

public Trial4C19Impl() {
    this.laboratories = new Laboratory[L];
    numLaboratories=0;
}

@Override
public void addLaboratory(String idLaboratory, String name) {

    if(laboratories != null) {
        for(int i=0; i<numLaboratories;i++) {
            if (laboratories[i].hasId(idLaboratory)) {
                laboratories[i].setName(name);
                encontrado=true;
            }
        }
        if(!encontrado) {
            this.laboratories[numLaboratories] = new Laboratory(idLaboratory, name);
            this.numLaboratories++; 
        }   
        
    }else {
        if(!encontrado) {
            this.laboratories[numLaboratories] = new Laboratory(idLaboratory, name);
            this.numLaboratories++; 
        }
    }
}

@Override
public Laboratory getLaboratory(String idLaboratory) {
    for(int i=0;i<laboratories.length;i++) {
        if (laboratories[i].hasId(idLaboratory)) {
            return this.laboratories[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int numLaboratories() {
    return this.numLaboratories;
}
}
```

La clase Laboratory es:

```
public class Laboratory {
private String id;
private String name;

public Laboratory (String idLaboratory, String name) {
    this.setId(idLaboratory);
    this.setName(name);
    
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean hasId(String id) {
    return this.id.equals(id);
}
}
```

Y los test que debo superar son:

```
    ////
    //// Añadimos Laboratories
    ////

    trial4C19.addLaboratory("LAB1","Lab ClÃ­nic 1");
    trial4C19.addLaboratory("LAB2","Lab ClÃ­nic 2");
    trial4C19.addLaboratory("LAB3","Lab ClÃ­nic 3");
    trial4C19.addLaboratory("LAB4","Lab ClÃ­nic 4");
    trial4C19.addLaboratory("LAB5","Lab ClÃ­nic 5");


    @Test
public void testAddLaboratory() {

    this.trial4C19.addLaboratory("LAB6", "LAB CLINIC 6");
    Assert.assertEquals("LAB CLINIC 6", this.trial4C19.getLaboratory("LAB6").getName());
    Assert.assertEquals(6, this.trial4C19.numLaboratories());

    this.trial4C19.addLaboratory("LAB7", "LAB XXXXXX");
    Assert.assertEquals("LAB XXXXXX", this.trial4C19.getLaboratory("LAB7").getName());
    Assert.assertEquals(7, this.trial4C19.numLaboratories());

    this.trial4C19.addLaboratory("LAB7", "LAB CLINIC 7");
    Assert.assertEquals("LAB CLINIC 7", this.trial4C19.getLaboratory("LAB7").getName());
    Assert.assertEquals(7, this.trial4C19.numLaboratories());
}
```

No se que hago mal en el método **addLaboratory** para que no se me añadan o modifiquen. Necesito una ayuda para continuar. Cuando Debugeo veo que existe un bucle con **if (laboratories[i].hasId(idLaboratory))** y no pasa de ahi, ni siquiera al else. Gracias

Comment: De igual forma, creo que utilizas un array estático. Si quieres agregar más elementos a un arreglo hay que programar un arreglo dinámico o una lista enlazada o alguna estructura que te permita hacerlo. La clase [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) te podría ser útil. De igual forma hacer linear search cada que añades un nuevo elemento no es buena idea si vas a añadir múltiples elementos, utliza binary search (`O(logn)`) con un heap, o un hashmap (`O(1)`) aparte para mejorar el rendimiento.

Comment: private Laboratory [ ] laboratories;

private int numLaboratories;

public Trial4C19Impl() {
        this.laboratories = new Laboratory[L]; //siendo L=15
    }

Comment: El array no puede pasar de 15 elementos, por eso utilizo un array. No es elección propia, sino impuesto. Puede que el error este efectivamente en que se esta intentando buscar cuando el array esta vacío y es nulo.

Comment: Si el campo numLaboratories es la cantidad de laboratorios que hay en el array entonces el bucle for debe recorrer hasta esta cantidad ( i < numLaboratories ). Pero para estar seguro debería ver toda la clase donde esta declarado el método. Y se tiene que verificar que el array no este lleno  antes de agregar otro Laboratory.

Comment: Edito el código del enunciado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siguiendo el código inicial y después de haber visto la clase:

1. En el array  se debe buscar el id hasta el número de Laboratory que hay en el array, indicado por el campo **numLaboratories**. (Evita que se evalúen posiciones con el valor null).

   for(int i = 0; i < numLaboratories ; i++)
2. Si el id no se encuentra, agregar el nuevo objeto Laboratory teniendo en cuenta que no se supere la capacidad del array (15).

   if(!encontrado && numLaboratories < 15)

EL siguiente código muestra las modificaciones en el código que publicaste originalmente:

```
    public void addLaboratory(String idLaboratory, String name) {

    boolean encontrado = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < numLaboratories ; i++) {

        if (laboratories[i].hasId(idLaboratory)) {
            laboratories[i].setName(name);
            encontrado=true;
        }
    }   
    if(!encontrado && numLaboratories < 15) {
        this.laboratories[numLaboratories] = new Laboratory(idLaboratory, name);
        this.numLaboratories++; 
    }
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Te lo agradezco mucho, era justo lo que necesitaba. Llevaba tantos años sin programar que no tengo la cabeza estructurada. gracias